# z-index = 1 and div position fixed does not work

Tags: css, z-index

in my website (under construction) I have a search box in the middle, this search post do some research in the database using ajax. Results display in a div which has z-index = 1 and position fixed under the search bar.

The trouble is that results are displaying in the back of the main page who has no z-index.

I've tried also with z-index = 100 but I have the same result

Instead of giving the entire code it is better for you to have a look directly at my website

here adress to access : http://www.changeyourbody.fr/index.php

and in the header for to login :

login : demo@demo.com
password : demodemo

you can type in the search box : "sp" or "gu" to see the beginning of the search.

I'm trying to put results of the search upper and not down the main div.

anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: I haven't checked your website but FYI, it is `z-index: 100` not `z-index= 100`.

Comment: yes I put z-index:100 but = 100 is just in the explaination

Comment: The issue is that you have your `position: fixed`. Just to tickle my fancy, try to set your `position: absolute`.

Comment: I set to absolute, I've clear the cache and have the same result as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the rule for your header class to the following seemed to fix it for me.

```
 .cyb-header {
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
```

Comment: thank you it works fine, So I understand that it must be the real parent and not the concerning div. But I had to change fixed by relative otherwise it has removed my background, now it works fine, thank you so much.

Comment: `z-index` doesn't work with `position: fixed`, `relative` or `absolute` is required for `z-index` to be effective

Comment: Yes, it does. Z-index works just fine on all three. @user2506760 - Your parent div is the one that is to be the whole width so that is the one to be fixed. Absolute or relative will not fix the header to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Z-index won't work on an element with position fixed. In order for z-index to work, you'll need to give the element a position:absolute or a position:relative.

But your problem can easily be solved by adding a z-index to your header:

```
.cyb-header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('../images/header.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  z-index: 5;  // New Line
}
```

It will work with `z-index: 1` but you can add some margin for future css and set it to 5.

Comment: thank you, for the explanation so I understood that it must be the first parent also. Thanks a lot